# How can one compare resonant and non resonant antenna based on parameters like Directivity, Radiation resistance, Cross polarisation, Efficiency?

Tags: antenna, communication, digital-communications, telecommunications, antenna-array

Basically I want to make a choice between two antennas when ample space is given objectively based on parameters

**1.Directivity**

**2.Radiation Resistance**

**3.Cross Polarization ratio**

**4.Loss resistance**

I'll consider both antennas to be of nearly same length i.e. the difference between length is only such that one is **(a)exactly resonant**

and other is
**(b)just short** or

**(c)just long**

to be called resonant all are operating at same wave length.

Comment: Now that's a decent question but, I thought you might also consider the loading and any attempt at resonant tuning? I guess that could come later maybe.